# Wait for a JS call to PHP to finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have a registration form in an iFrame on my main window. When the user submits the form, a PHP is called to insert the data in the database. Once this is done, I call a function in the parent window which closes the iFrame. Unfortunately, the iFrame is closing before the PHP can finish. Is there a way for me to call the close iFrame function ONLY AFTER the PHP returns "true"?

Here is the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {
        // Send the data to the server
        document.getElementById("form1").submit();

    // Call the 'close iframe' function in my parent window
    parent.closeIFrame();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Submitting the form would refresh the iframe.

So in your return content from PHP, call the function in the parent window.

```
if(parent && parent.closeIFrame){
  parent.closeIframe();
}
```

Comment: Are you saying I should put the lines you gave me at the end of my PHP? I did that and I got this error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function closeIFrame() in /home/mhd-01/www.mysite.com/htdocs/php/register.php on line 22 and line 22 reads: if(parent && parent.closeIFrame) parent.closeIFrame();

Comment: I finally got it to work calling this function: var closeIFrame = function() { $('#regcontainer').remove(); }. Now I have a different problem. If I try to open it again, it doesn't. Any ideas?